# Ontology Object Properties Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, ontology, protege, object-properties

I have developed an Arabic ontology about chest diseases using Protege 5.2.0, the ontology has a class `Disease` and a class `Symptom`. The object property between the previous two classes is `has_symptom` which the domain of it is `Disease` and the range is `Symptom`. Now I have a sub class of a class `Disease` which is `Tuberculosis`. 
 Now can I query the ontology to get the object property between the class `Tuberculosis`  and the class `Symptom` see the following query:
 
`PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ali/ontologies/2017/2/CDDOnto#>
 SELECT ?property
 WHERE {
    ?property rdfs:domain my:Tuberculosis ;
              rdfs:range my:Symptom .
 }`

Should I get the same property which is between the class `Disease` which is a super class of `Tuberculosis` and the class `Symptom` or not?
 In other words is the object property inherited by the sub classes of its domain and range.
I appreciate any help you provide.

Answer (score 1):

No, introducing the `my:Tuberculosis rdfs:subClassOf my:Disease` axiom to your dataset does not imply that `my:has_symptom rdfs:domain my:Tuberculosis`.

You could possibly query for the property by looking for properties where `my:Tuberculosis` is a sub-class of the domain of the property. The following query should retrieve properties whose domain is a super-class of `my:Tuberculosis`.

```
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
 PREFIX my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ali/ontologies/2017/2/CDDOnto#>
 SELECT ?property
 WHERE {
    ?property rdfs:domain/(rdfs:subClassOf^)* my:Tuberculosis ;
              rdfs:range my:Symptom .
 }
```

Depending on how you have defined your ontology (ie: are you using owl axioms?), you may be better off using an owl reasoner. For example, if your class hierarchy includes any union or intersection axioms, that above query would not be 'smart' enough to follow them.